# Google Sheets API - Does expanding or collapsing a group trigger an event?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am working on a sheet that has three separate row groups that I don't want all expanded at the same time. I only want one expanded at a time, so I'm trying to write a script that will collapse the other row groups when one is expanded. My plan was to use the onEdit(e) simple trigger to collapse the other rows, but there doesn't seem to be an event triggered when you toggle a group.

Am I mistaken? Is there a way to do this? Or can you suggest a different way to achieve my objective?

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, feel free to tell me. I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: Hi! Sorry for the late reply. This solution hasn't given me exactly what I want, but I feel like its on the way! My current issue is that the onChange trigger is called which is good, and the event object is OTHER, which is also good. But I can't figure out a way to find out which range caused the trigger. I essentially want to say, if range A was expanded, collapse range B and range C. But I can't tell who caused the trigger because they all have the same triggerUid. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm really sorry for my incomplete answer. I posted an answer including a sample script. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: With some tweaks, this gave me exactly what I needed. I was unaware about the PropertiesService class. That will prove very useful in the future. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By installing the function as a trigger of OnChange, the function can be run when expanding and collapsing occur. At that time, `changeType` of the event object is `OTHER`.

#### Reference:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#g_suite_application_triggers)
- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change)

### Edit:

Unfortunately, the event object of OnChange doesn't include the detail information when the OnChange event was triggered. So as a workaround, how about using PropertiesService? In this workaround, it retrieves the status using PropertiesService.

As a sample situation, it supposes as follows.

- Row 3-5 is groupA
- Row 8-10 is groupB
- Row 13-15 is groupC

For above situation, it uses the following script.

#### Sample script:

```
function onChange(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet(); // or you can also use SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() === "Sheet1") { // If you want to control the sheet. Please put the sheet name here.
    var p = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
    var s = p.getProperties();
    var groupA = sheet.getRowGroup(3, 1);
    var groupB = sheet.getRowGroup(8, 1);
    var groupC = sheet.getRowGroup(13, 1);
    var gA = groupA.isCollapsed().toString() === s.groupA;
    var gB = groupB.isCollapsed().toString() === s.groupB;
    var gC = groupC.isCollapsed().toString() === s.groupC;
    if (gA && gB && gC) {
      return;
    } else if (!gA && gB && gC && !groupA.isCollapsed()) {
      groupB.collapse();
      groupC.collapse();
    } else if (gA && !gB && gC && !groupB.isCollapsed()) {
      groupA.collapse();
      groupC.collapse();
    } else if (gA && gB && !gC && !groupC.isCollapsed()) {
      groupA.collapse();
      groupB.collapse();
    }
    var currentStatus = {groupA: groupA.isCollapsed(), groupB: groupB.isCollapsed(), groupC: groupC.isCollapsed()};
    p.setProperties(currentStatus);
  }
  return;
}
```

#### Note:

- When you use this, please copy and paste this script and install `onChange()` as a trigger of OnCange.
- Please set your sheet name to `"Sheet1"` of `if (sheet.getSheetName() === "Sheet1") {`.
- This script works as follows.

  - When groupA is expanded, groupB and groupC are collapsed.
  - When groupB is expanded, groupA and groupC are collapsed.
  - When groupC is expanded, groupA and groupB are collapsed.
  - When all groups are collapsed, this script is nothing to do.
- If the quick operation for expanding and collapsing is done, the response error might occure.

#### References:

- [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service)
- [getRowGroup()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrowgrouprowindex-groupdepth)
- [isCollapsed()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/group#isCollapsed())